# How to make macro's inline in Confluence

Tags: confluence

I am trying to use the highlight macro to highlight a word inline, similar to this:

I only want the word `this` to be grey.

When I use the Confluence editor, I create this:

[image: confluence edit]

Next, I ensure that inline display is selected:

[image: confluence inline]

I include no new lines, and no matter what I get this output:

[image]

What am I missing to make the entire sentence appear on the same line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One answer is to put the whole line in a {wiki} macro, like so:

{wiki} `I only want {highlight:gray} this {highlight} word to be gray.` {wiki}

Seems crazy but I could not get the inline button to work for me at all.